# Need a way to batch extract screen captures from a folder using ffmpeg

Tags: windows-10, ffmpeg, video, batch

I have about 300 lectures in a folder, the last frame from each video is important
I can use

```bash
ffmpeg -sseof -3 -i input -update 1 -q:v 1 last.jpg
```

to take a single file's last frame and save it to a specified name. I want to input all the videos together and output them preserving the name of the file without having to do the laborious work of specifying it each time. I dont know if any wildcards are accepted or how to do any loop.

Please provide some suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a batch file, you can do like this :

---

```bat
@echo off
Title Extract ScreenShot With FFMPEG
@for %%i in (*.mkv *.mp4 *.webm) do ffmpeg -sseof -3 -i "%%i" -update 1 -q:v 1 "%%~ni.jpg"
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
for %i in (*.webm) do ffmpeg -sseof -3 -i "%i" -update 1 -q:v 1 "%~ni.jpg"
```

I think this would do.